# Как установить Jax для Python

Tags: python, cuda

Пытаюсь установить Jax с поддержкой GPU на Python 3.7 (Windows 10, CUDA 11.3, numpy 1.21) по инструкции на сайте https://github.com/google/jax
В cmd ввожу следующие команды:

```
pip install numpy scipy six wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda111]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
ERROR: Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on
PyPI.jax depends on jaxlib@ https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/cuda111/jaxlib-0.1.67+cuda111
-cp37-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [readme.md](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/README.md#installation) указаны поддерживаемые платформы для установки.

> We support installing or building jaxlib on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 or later) and macOS (10.12 or later) platforms. Windows users can use JAX on CPU and GPU via the Windows Subsystem for Linux. There is some initial native Windows support, but since it is still somewhat immature, there are no binary releases and it must be built from source.

В Windows доступна установка только на [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/about).
То есть, если оставаться в Windows, нужно следовать инструкции из ссылки выше: установить WSL, дистрибутив Linux с магазина Microsoft Store, а далее ставить jax уже в терминале wsl.